# In cart only one seller product can be added in one time

Tags: magento

I need help in magneto, In cart only one seller product can be added in one time.
other seller product should be restricted.

This is code to control based on sku

```
$product = $this->_initProduct();
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item) {
    if($item->sku() == $product->sku()) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->addItem($item);
        return $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
     }
```

Like this I need to control one seller product at a time

Comment: Questions are more easily answered if you include the code. Also, I would go a bit more in depth on the description of your problem.

Comment: So what is your problem

Comment: Format code in more readable fashion